# How to upload and configure old website files from an old domin name to a new one?

Tags: config, downloading-website-files

How do I upload website files from an old domain name to a new one, both registered with GoDaddy, on a GoDady hosting account and properly configure it to work on the new domain name.

The old domain name expired and wasn't renewed on time. Now it's unavailable and a new one was purchased. Now I want to upload the files associated with the old domain name to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you just need to copy the files and upload it to your new website. If you encounter issue, you can contact your hosting provider directly.